# Capitalize Shortcode Value on Output

Tags: php, shortcode

I wrote this shortcode to take a filename I specify and output it as an image with title and alt tags:

```
function cwc_pkmn($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "name" => 'http://',
    ), $atts));
    return '<img src="/path/to/file/'.$name.'.png" alt="'.$name.'" title="'.$name.'" />';
}
add_shortcode("pkmn", "cwc_pkmn");
```

All of my filenames are lowercase with a "-" between words. Is it possible to have the output capitalize each letter following a - and replace the - with spaces? So right now, when I do the shortcode above like this:

```
[pkmn name="mr.-deeds"]
```

I get this as the output:

```
<img src="/path/to/file/mr.-deeds.png" alt="mr.-deeds" title="mr.-deeds">
```

But is it possible to have the output do this instead with the title and alt tags?:

```
<img src="/path/to/file/mr.-deeds.png" alt="Mr. Deeds" title="Mr. Deeds">
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. . .

```
function cwc_pkmn( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
{
    // ------------------------
    // Settings:
    $path     = '/path/to/file/';
    $ext      = 'png';
    // ------------------------

    // Shortcode input:
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array( 'name' => '' ),
        $atts,
        'pkmn_shortcode'
    );

    // Sanitize input:
    $name          =  esc_attr( $atts['name'] );

    // Init:
    $words_ucfirst = array();

    // Capitalize the first letter in each word:
    $words         = explode( '-', $name );

    foreach( $words as $word )
    {
        $words_ucfirst[] =  ucfirst( $word );
    }

    $name_mod = esc_attr( join( ' ', $words_ucfirst ) );

    return sprintf( '<img src="%s%s.%s" alt="%s" title="%s" />',
        $path,
        $name,
        $ext,
        $name_mod,
        $name_mod
    );
}

add_shortcode( 'pkmn', 'cwc_pkmn' );
```

Comment: Wow that was fast! However, it didn't work. :( The images all broke too. :(

Comment: I hope you guys don't mind the rewrite, it should work as expected now. Otherwise just rollback to the previous revision ;-)

Comment: This is still not working for me. :( I get a blank file name, alt tag, and title tag in the HTML output.

Comment: @Jon I updated the code snippet and tested it, should work now ;-)

Comment: @birgire don't mind the rewrite, hahaha. +1 to you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for this. It uses regular expressions to replace part of a string. Using the regular expression "-[a-z]" matches a dash followed by a lowercase letter. Adding parentheses around the [a-z] allows us to use it in the replacement function (`function( $matches )`) allows us to use it in `$matches`. The return value of the function is used to replace the matched string. This way, we replace -[a-z] to a space followed by the uppercase letter that was lowercase before.

```
$title = preg_replace_callback( '/\-([a-z])/', function( $matches ) {
    return ' ' . strtoupper( $matches[1] );
}, $name );
```

Comment: Thanks! Where would I put that though? When I tried it like this, it didn't work:

function cwc_pkmn($atts) {
 extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  "name" => 'http://',
 ), $atts));

$title = preg_replace_callback( '/\-([a-z])/', function( $matches ) {
    return ' ' . strtoupper( $matches[1] );
}, $name );

 return '<img src="http://static.staging.pokebeach.com/wp/themes/pokebeach/images/sprites/'.$name.'.png" alt="'.$name.'" title="'.$name.'" class="pkmn" />';
}
add_shortcode("pkmn", "cwc_pkmn");

Comment: Well, you need to do *some* thinking yourself... What is stored in the `$title` variable? The title. Where do you want the title? In the `title` and `alt` attributes. So where do you put it...?

Comment: I'm very inexperienced in PHP and tried every way I could think of to get this to work. It was a miracle I even managed to get a shortcode written - took me 2 hours of playing with the code and researching how it works. So would you be able to give me a bigger hint? <3

Comment: Simply use the code you commented with but use `$title` in the `name` and `title` tags.